# Apache2 installation : libaprutil-1.so.0 => not found

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I was installing apache2 on Ubuntu 13.10, but after installation I tried to run apache showin error:

```
$ sudo ./httpd start
./httpd: error while loading shared libraries: libaprutil-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried solutions given on web, none of them working, please help!!

```
$ ldd httpd
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff05fe000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f60741a5000)
    libaprutil-1.so.0 => not found
    libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007f6073f71000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6073d54000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f607398c000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f6073786000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6073582000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f60743d9000)
```

Comment: Wrong community buddy try here http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 7):

This issue was probably resolved, but you were probably missing the package `libapr1`: Apache Portable Runtime library.
For Debian based operating systems such as Ubuntu, run:

```
sudo apt-get install libapr1
```

For Fedora based systems the package is `apr-util`:

```
sudo yum install apr-util
```

or

```
sudo dnf install apr-util
```

Then try running apache again.

Comment: Thank you. Used the fedora command for RHEL 8.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't invoke httpd directly.  Most distributions provide a script that sets up the environment, including shared library path -- such as apachectl or apachectl2 or the sysv-init script.

Comment: yes I tried apachectl, same problem                                 $ sudo ./apachectl start
/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd: error while loading shared libraries: libaprutil-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: /usr/local implies you built it yourself.  Looks like you don't have a usable aprutil in your shared library path, and there's no packager responsible for it but you.

Install something that satisfied the dependency.